# Task Scheduler (run whether user is logged on or not)

Tags: windows-7, batch-file, windows-task-scheduler

I'm having a problem with scheduling a task in Windows 7 I m creating a task which is mapped to a bat file to execute, here is my .bat file :

```
cd "C:\soft\" 
Start excel "" "AD Auto Run.xlsm"
```

its working automaticaly and manually when the option (radio button) "Run only when the user is logged on" is selected.

but the automatic/manual RUN is not working when the option (radio button) "Run whether user logged on or not" is selected.

PS: I don't use a mapped drive

Comment: Is the batch file within a user's profile? Can you set it to have admin rights? If it can't get into the user's folders, it won't be able to execute the file.

Comment: hwo can I set up user Profile ?

Comment: The user profile is the profile of the user that is logged in. I know, that's backwards talking. Go to `control panel - user accounts`